# PostgreSQL How can you display icons in select query resullts

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi do any one knows how to display icons instead of values in a PostgreSQL query ?
for example i have this output

```
name, number_of_appels 
Jack, 1, 
Annie, 3, 
Tim,5,
```

i want it to be displayed like this

```
name, number_of_appels,appels 
Jack, 1, apple-icon 
Annie, 3, apple-icon *3 
Tim,5,apple-icon *5
```

any ides please ?

Comment: IMO: This would be done in a UI outside of a database when it's rendering results.  This isn't innate DB Functionality of which I'm aware.

Comment: The database engine can perfectly store and retrieve raw data such as images, videos, audio, etc. It's the job of the UI to "render" that raw data in the required way, not the database.

Comment: when you like red, or green, apples, you can also use `select repeat(convert_from('\xF09F8d8e','utf8'),3), repeat(convert_from('\xF09F8D8F','utf8'),4);`

Comment: thnx @Luuk this exactly what i need, i did"nt even know that this option existed before, thnx man

Comment: Solved thnx to @Luuk

Comment: @Luuk how can find the other forms other than the appels ? do you have documentation link for this option ?

Comment: @luuk  love learnining about new things.  Thanks!

Comment: @OUSSAMABEYGAHAR  https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=127872&utf8=string-literal

Comment: thnx @Luuk , i was able to use it , it turned out i need to add \x before the utf-8 code i dont know why but it worked that way thnx man

Answer (score 0):

when you like red, or green, apples, you can also use select repeat(convert_from('\xF09F8d8e','utf8'),3), repeat(convert_from('\xF09F8D8F','utf8'),4);
solved thnx to @luuk